# DCC Hint: H2161 Warning: Duplicate resource: Type 24 (user-defined), ID 1; File resource ... kept; file ...\WindowsXP.res resource discarded

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Get the following error while linking my project in Delphi XE2. Recreating of .dproj file doesn't help.

`[DCC Hint] H2161 Warning: Duplicate resource:  Type 24 (user-defined), ID 1; File resource <filename>.res kept; file c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\9.0\lib\Win32\release\WindowsXP.res resource discarded.`

How to fix it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a note: I have noticed that from at least D2010 up (possibly D2009 up), the IDE cache sometimes gets in the way and you can get duplicate resource warnings on compiles. Do a build and they are gone.  So nowadays whenever I see a duplicate resource warning, I first do a build and only start hunting if that doesn't clear it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You've got more than one application manifest linked to the application. There can be only one and so some have to be discarded. Modern Delphi versions link a manifest by default based on the "Runtime themes" project option. You possibly have another manifest linked, perhaps dating from when you developed the project in an earlier version of Delphi. Are you using the [TXPManifest](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XPMan.TXPManifest) component by any chance?

You can remove the manifest that you are explicitly linking. Or you can disable the runtime themes setting and retain the explicit manifest. That latter way you are in control of the manifest. Personally that is the way I do it because I do need to have control over precisely what goes in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks. But no one runtime theme is selected. I have tried to delete the one XPManifest on the main form - error still exists:(

Comment: There has to be another manifest somewhere! It's a question of hunting it down.

Comment: Search by string 'TXPManifest' shows no results on all components and files of the project.

Comment: search for $R which links resources. Have you just upgraded delphi?

Comment: Deleting the TXPManifest component isn't good enough. You have to remove the XPMan unit from your form's `uses` clause, too. (Adding the component adds the unit automatically, but removing the component doesn't remove the unit because the IDE cannot *know* that removing the unit is the correct thing to do. As we see in this case, the unit has side effects beyond just providing the component, and the IDE doesn't know whether you still want those side effects.)

Comment: Thanks @rob. I've never used XPman myself but I guess the only way the resource can be linked is by including a unit with a $R.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: on a side note, XE2 introduces the ability to specify a custom manifest instead of using the default manifest.  Go to `Project > Options > Application`, set `Runtime Themes` to `Use custom manifest`, and specify the filename of your .manifest file. You would still have to remove `XPMan` from the project, but this way you can now add additional criteria to the project manifest (UAC elevation, side-by-side assemblies, registration-free COM, etc).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and arrived on this page via Google.

Removing `XPMan` from the uses-clause fixed it.

Found the culprit via "find in files" with search term "xpman". Thanks for Rob Kennedy for suggesting this in the comment to David's answer.

Comment: Same here with the samples that came with Delphi Tokyo. They have XPMan in the uses list; if you uncheck 'Enable runtime themes', it will be re-checked for you ;-)

Comment: I was screwed after I removed XPManifest from Form1 and added xp_uac.res. This was XPMan in uses clause causing the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your help.
For me, the following has helped:

```
{$ R * .RES} from project source removed
```

Comment: Yes. Only removing helped me too. Removing XPMan from uses-clause nothing changes- it is created automatically..

Answer (score -1):

Removing `{$R *.res}` from project source helps. `{$R *.res}` is restricted in Delphi XE2?

Comment: That doesn't sound like the answer. You would be better using runtime themes option in project options if you want to influence the main app resource. Look for xpman unit as rob suggested.

Comment: Removing {$R *.res} might have "as if solved" effect if you have included a manifest in your custom RC/RES file. It is better to remove the manifest from the custom RES file instead of deleting the whole RES reference.